# C/C++ freeing a pointer by calling reference or directly

Tags: c++, c, pointers

```
struct State {
    int* maxLiters;
    int* nowLiters;
} parentState;

void makeState(State& s) {
    if ((s.maxLiters = (int*)malloc(cups*sizeof(int))) == nullptr) {
        error();
    }
    if ((s.nowLiters = (int*)malloc(cups*sizeof(int))) == nullptr) {
        error();
    }
}

void delState(State& s) { // or delState(State s) ?
    free(s.maxLiters);
    free(s.nowLiters);
}
```

I have always been coding in C, and am really at the start of doing C++. My apologies for using 'malloc'.

In the 'delState' function, I have passed the struct by reference. I am a little not sure whether it is also okay to pass this by value, as in the comment. In C I would normally do this with a pointer, to consistently place an '&' when calling the making and deleting functions. Since with a reference parameter I should not type an '&', I am tempted to make a pure call-by-value function. Thinking about it myself does say 'okay' because either way, by reference or by value, the 'free' function will get the same memory address. But I'm just worried because I have never done this.

Helpful would be any clarifications, for which thanks in advance.

Comment: No passing by value won't be right, all operations would apply to a copy of `s`. Also just use a `std::vector<int>` instead of managing the memory yourself.

Comment: Assuming `State` doesn't do deep copy, it doesn't matter. `free` operates on the pointer, which is copied. Of course, making it a reference, we could set the pointers to `NULL` to avoid double free.

Comment: Also, if you really want to go toward c++, consider the idea of adding a destructor to your struct rather than an external function (other than using new and delete rather than mallon and free) and keep this (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)) in mind.

Comment: Really: I don't see a parameter passing problem here, I see a quite eviden design one. I don't know where to start from... Where is "cup"? Where is "error()"? Why using C++ if not classes are being used, nor struct methods?

Comment: @WhozCraig He should probably NOT be calling new and delete in this case. Probably should be using vector.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ: Passing the struct by value to function `delState` seems fine (on 32-bit systems you would be pushing 4 more bytes into the stack, but no other impact besides that).

Comment: @CashCow that would be... Slide #7.

Comment: @barakmanos I'd say without more context, it may generate more of a confusion for the OP, to tell him it's just OK to pass by value (despite of it will work fine in this particular case).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are wanting to use C++ it's better to learn the "C++ way" of doing things. In this case, you should not really be calling functions to create and delete your state for you, instead you should use class constructors and destructors. Also, instead of using arrays, it's generally best to use std::vector. For your example, this would look like:

```
class State {
public:
    State (size_t cups) 
       : maxLiters(cups), nowLiters(cups) //reserve "cups" amount of space in the vectors
    { }

    ~State () =default; //default destructor, will call the vector destructors and delete the data automatically
    State (const State &other) =default //default copy constructor, will copy the contents of the vectors into a new State object
    State &operator= (const State &other) =default //default assignment operator, will overwrite the contents of this object with the new one

    std::vector<int> maxLiters;
    std::vector<int> nowLiters;    
};
```

Then if you want to handle out-of-memory errors, you would do this when creating a state object:

```
try
{
    State s(12);
    ...
}
catch (std::bad_alloc &ba)
{
    error();
}
```

However, it doesn't often make sense to catch a bad_alloc exception, as recovering from something like that ranges from hard to impossible, especially if some data-structures were corrupted when the exception was thrown.

Now that your class manages heap-allocated data, you should think about what it should mean to copy and assign objects of this class and define a copy constructor and assignment operator overload if the defaults won't cut it for you. This is known as the [Rule of Three](http://www.drdobbs.com/c-made-easier-the-rule-of-three/184401400).

You should also think about encapsulating your vectors by declaring them private and providing getters/setters for them. This is good practice even if you declare both getters and setters for sake of interface consistency.

Comment: Pay attention: it seems that he's not trying to allocate a simple int, but an array of them...

Comment: Whoops, I didn't see that `cups*`

Comment: Maybe because nobody saw a "cups" declaration. I wonder if it's some sort of global variable.

Comment: Very clever. Post a poor answer, then edit in my answer to yours and get 2 upvotes.

Comment: Comparing the answers, they look very similar, but that's because it's a very basic implementation; I didn't look at yours before my edit. I'm happy to delete the answer if you feel mortally offended.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the advice to use constructors/destructors along with vector is the one you should take to resolve this very issue. However, I think there are two important things that you should look at in this context, because at some point you may need to do manual allocation.

### RAII-Idiom ([Resource Allocation Is Initialization](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization))

To sum up what its use means: You never use functions to allocate/free resources, but let constructors/destructors handle this. In your case it would mean that you create a constructor for state, which does the allocation of the arrays, and a destructor, which does the free. I mention this even though I agree with previous answers, which advise you to use vector, because I think that, if you are in a situation where you have to do manual allocation it is good to know. You should not use allocation/free functions the way you did, because c++ has exceptions, so you are not guaranteed to reach the code where you call the free function. Therefor you would also have to handle the free in the exception routine, whereas the destructors would be called automatically in most cases.

### Smart Pointers

These could also be an option in this case for you, if you want to make the minimum possible changes. In c++ you should always use a smart pointer if you can do so (which is pretty much always). In the new standard there are 2 types of smart pointers: unique pointer and shared pointer. Both would deserve a long explanation, but I will defer this ([unique pointer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr), [shared pointer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)). It would be smart to read up on those even beyond the definitions I linked, because those two are very powerful. Unique pointer allows you to have a pointer that cannot be copied and that will handle the deallocation of the object it points to once it goes out of scope. Shared pointer stores a reference count and will deallocate the object it points to once the count reaches 0. In combination with RAII these pointers will usually allow you to write code without explicit manual allocation, which is usually what you would want in c++. If you cannot use the smart pointers from c++11, you should consider [boost's smart pointers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm).

Answer (score 0):

> Blockquote 
>    I have always been coding in C, and am really at the start of doing C++

You need to write `C++` as `C++`, where, although you are also responsible in some ways for memory management (i.e. there is no garbage collection, in general) you do not normally directly delete your memory but use the provided library to take care of the memory for you.

Whwatever `cups` is, it looks like your `State` class contains two vectors.

```
class State
{
     // note these members are private

   std::vector< int > maxLiters_;
   std::vector< int > nowLiters_;

 public:
   explicit State( size_t cups )
         : maxLiters_( cups )
         ,  nowLiters_( cups )
   {
   }

   std::vector<int> const& maxLiters() const
  {
    return maxLiters_;
   }

   std::vector< int > const& nowLiters() const
  {
      return nowLiters ;
  }
};

int main()
{
    State state( 6 );

   // whatever
}
```

No need to free anything. The vectors are owned by the class. If you copy your class your vectors will be copied to make new copies. If you want different semantics you'd probably use a `shared_ptr`.

`C++` is a different language and you'll need to learn to use it and not think in terms of how you'd implement it in `C`. (or Java, C#, Python, Perl or any other language).

Incidentally with your implementation (even as `C` if you remove the references etc.) you have an issue if the first `malloc` succeeds but the second one fails. Do you know which one actually failed? Will you know whether or not to `free` the first one?

You could take care of that by setting both pointers to nullptr before you try to allocate anything but you didn't.